# Okta multi-factor authentication at both Organization and Application level

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, okta, multi-factor-authentication, okta-api

I am trying to setup Okta MFA at both organization and app level for my AWS Application. I have successfully created the Sign On Policy for the AWS App and it is working correctly from Okta Console.

But now I want to add this feature in my Java Project, I tried searching for APIs which can be used to verify MFA at Application level, but I am not able to find any such API. Can you please provide me some details regarding application level mfa and how to do it from Java Project.

As of now I am able to Authenticate with MFA at account level. But when I try to use the same URL(https://?onetimetoken='SessionToken' ) for application level mfa, I am being redirected to the login page again.

Any idea how to implement App level MFA with Java?

Answer (score 0):

[These are the docs](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java#list-a-users-enrolled-factors) you are looking for! Basically, what you will want to do is use our Java SDK to enroll a user in a factor, then activate the factor, and finally, verify the factor when someone logs into your Java application.